# Is there a way to parallelize boto3's list_objects_v2 method?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I currently have a location in our s3 bucket that needs to be archived each hour with up to 6 million files in the most busy hour. The current logic looks something like this:

```
def get_responses(bucket, prefix):
    """
        This method will get the file information for a given directory on s3.
        Args:
            bucket (str): name of s3 bucket
            prefix (str): directory within s3 bucket
        Returns:
            list of json responses from S3
    """
    client = boto3.client(
        "s3", aws_access_key_id=S3_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET_KEY)
    continuation_token = None
    responses = []
    # List objects within the given directory until the response is truncated
    while True:
        list_kwargs = dict(
            Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, MaxKeys=1000)
        # Add continuation token if not None
        if continuation_token:
            list_kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token
        response = client.list_objects_v2(**list_kwargs)
        # Add valid reponses and update continuation token
        if 'Contents' in response:
            responses += response['Contents']
        # Exit while loop if at the end of the objects
        if not response.get('IsTruncated'):
            break
        continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')

    return responses
```

As you can see this iterates over 1000 files at a time, the current limit for list_objects_v2. In the worst case this takes roughly a half hour and slows down the overall job that this is part of which preferably would run in far under an hour. Is there a way to parallelize this so that you could have 1000 files being listed on each thread at a time?

(All files are under one prefix and can't be split)

Answer (score 1):

If there were N unique prefixes then perhaps you could use stock Python multi-processing/multi-threading features to make N independent calls, aggregating the results at the end.

If all objects have the same prefix, I'm not sure you could list subsets in parallel because you wouldn't know the NextContinuationToken in advance. But you might be able to fabricate some unique prefixes ...

If all objects have the same prefix e.g. `dogs/`, then you could list sub-prefixes such as `dogs/a`, `dogs/b`, `dogs/c`. etc. Do this for all possible first letters of the terminating filename. The prefix doesn't have to terminate on a forward slash such as `dogs/`. If you need more than 26 prefixes (assuming they are lowercase) then you could extend to `dogs/aa`, `dogs/ab`, etc. using the first 2 letters.

Alternatively, and again if you have N unique prefixes, then take a look at the Netflix [Metaflow](https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow) project, which claims to offer parallel S3 operation support, including for path listings:

> List the next level of paths in S3. If multiple keys are specified, listings are done in parallel.

Comment: Unfortunately it's one prefix, not N unique prefixes. This is the challenge, and yes it's because there isn't a way to get a NextContinuationToken in advance or several and farm them out to tasks. Still hopeful someone comes along with an answer but we'll see.

Comment: How long a time is there between the last object landing under that prefix and the need to list the objects under that prefix? If more than 24 hours, you might be able to use S3 Inventory. Or, perhaps you could accumulate a list of objects as they arrive in S3, via Lambda function writing to DynamoDB or equivalent, so that the list of objects is available instantly and can be partitioned for subsequent batch operations as needed.

Comment: You could also simply fabricate prefixes such as dogs/a, dogs/b, dogs/c. etc. Do this for all possible first letters of the terminating filename. The prefix doesn't have to terminate on a forward slash. If you need more than 26 prefixes (assuming their lowercased) then you can extend to dogs/aa, dogs/ab, etc. using the first 2 letters.

Comment: This is needed as quickly as we can list them, can't use the s3 inventory. That second piece you mentioned is interesting. Right now the set of files and some relevant metadata is written to an Aurora instance. I'd have to ballpark the cost of hitting that Lambda millions of times per hour + the DynamoDB and whether it could handle this many concurrent connections

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with the incomplete prefix, if that's the case then that's my best bet.

Comment: Yup, there's nothing special about the `/` forward slash within an S3 key. S3 essentially has a flat keyspace. It's no more special than `a` or `b` or `K`.